# build and run gem5-gpu with the x86 CPU ISA

Tags: 14.04, compiling

I have problem during build and run of gem5-gpu. Build the following code,

```
scons build/X86_VI_hammer_GPU/gem5.opt --default=X86 EXTRAS=../gem5-gpu/src:../gpgpu-sim/ PROTOCOL=VI_hammer GPGPU_SIM=True
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C header file Python.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library pthread... (cached) yes
Checking for C library dl... (cached) yes
Checking for C library util... (cached) yes
Checking for C library m... (cached) yes
Checking for C library python2.7... (cached) yes
Checking for accept(0,0,0) in C++ library None... (cached) yes
Checking for zlibVersion() in C++ library z... (cached) yes
Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++ library protobuf... 
(cached) yes
Checking for clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library None... (cached) yes
Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library None... (cached) no
Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library rt... (cached) yes
Checking for C library tcmalloc... (cached) yes
Checking for backtrace_symbols_fd((void*)0, 0, 0) in C library None... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file fenv.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file linux/kvm.h... (cached) yes
Checking size of struct kvm_xsave ... (cached) yes
Checking for member exclude_host in struct perf_event_attr...(cached) yes
Error: directory '/home/cust/gem5-gpu/src' does not exist
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Do that `Clone gem5-gpu glue code` ?

After that do `hg clone http://gem5-gpu.cs.wisc.edu/repo/gem5-gpu`
in gem5-gpu main directory, you will get the extra codes.

And `scons` to build the project ran at gem5-gpu/gem5,
then your command should work.